How to set subdomain rules for CORS in express.js?
I have a Web application with the front end as a React.js app, and the back end as a Node.js app using express.js. I intend to use as little money as possible for deploying these as this is for a personal project, so I am using Netlify for hosting the front end (free) and Heroku for hosting the back end ($0.010/hr).
My current setup for the front end on Netlify supports per-branch deployment on different URLs with the branch as a prefix like so: feature123 deployed on myurl.netlify.com will be deployed as feature123--myurl.netlify.com.
I need money per back-end deployment, so I don't want to spin up new back-end instances per branch. Instead, I want to deploy only one back-end and have all my front-end instances (variations per branch) use the same back-end instance.
The issue:
I have to set up CORS for my back-end and I want to avoid adding CORS rules for each branch on the front-end. What I am looking for is a rule something like *myurl.netlify.com, which covers any source coming from my source. How do I achieve this?

With help cors library you can achieve this by passing Regexp or Array of string/Regexp to origin option as mentioned here.
An example could be like this
cors({
  origin: [
    'https://myurl.netlify.app', 
    /^https:\/\/[0-9A-Za-z]+--myurl\.netlify\.app$/
  ],
  // ....
})

